# Send custom email template from custom mdoule Magento 1.9

Tags: magento-1.9, custom, email-templates

`In config.xml`

```
<template>
    <email>
        <custom_order_tpl module="Amasty_Xnotif">
            <label>Lowstock E Mail </label>
            <file>statusmail_processing.html</file>
            <type>html</type>
        </custom_order_tpl>
    </email>
</template>
```

template file at `app/locale/en_US/template/email/statusmail_processing.html`

```
<!--@subject Products low stock alert @-->
<div>
    <h1>Dear {{var username}}</h1>
    <div>{{var storename}} ({{var store_url}})</div>
</div>
```

In `Observer.php`

```
public function getAlertFrontend(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
{
    // customer_id, product_id, customer_email,
    Mage::log('we are in cataloginventory frontend log start ');
    $event = $observer->getEvent();
    $order = $event->getOrder();
    $orderId = $order->getIncrementId();  // working
    $customer = $order->getCustomer();
    $orderItem = $order->getItem();
    $customerEmail = $order->getCustomerEmail(); // working  Required

    foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
        $items[] = array(
            'product_id'    => $item->getProductId(),
            'name'          => $item->getName(),
            'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
            'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
            'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
        );

        $productId = $item->getProductId();
        $productName= $item->getName();
    }

    $stock_qtyNotify = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId)->getNotifyStockQty();
    $stock_qty = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($productId)->getQty();

    if( $stock_qty < $stock_qtyNotify ) {
        foreach ($order->getAllItems() as $item) {
            $items[] = array(
                'product_id'    => $item->getProductId(),
                'name'          => $item->getName(),
                'sku'           => $item->getSku(),
                'Price'         => $item->getPrice(),
                'Ordered Qty'   => $item->getQtyOrdered(),
            );

            $productId = $item->getProductId();
            $productName= $item->getName();
        }

        $customer_stock_alerts = Mage::getModel('productalert/stock')
            ->getCollection()
            ->addFieldToFilter('product_id', $productId)
            ->addFieldToFilter('status', 0);
        // Mage::log( $customer_stock_alerts );

        foreach ( $customer_stock_alerts as $alert ) {
            Mage::log('Inside loop');
            Mage::log($alert->getEmail());  // works
            try {
                // Email template starts
                $emailTemplate  = Mage::getModel('core/email_template');
                $emailTemplate->loadDefault('custom_order_tpl');
                $emailTemplate->setTemplateSubject('Products low stock alert');

                // Get General email address (Admin->Configuration->General->Store Email Addresses)
                $salesData['email'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/email');
                $salesData['name'] = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_general/name');

                $emailTemplate->setSenderName($salesData['name']);
                $emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($salesData['email']);
                $emailTemplateVariables['username']  = $order->getCustomerFirstname() . ' ' . $order->getCustomerLastname();

                $emailTemplateVariables['store_name'] = $order->getStoreName();
                $emailTemplateVariables['store_url'] = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_WEB);

                Mage::log(var_export($emailTemplateVariables, true), NULL, 'custom_email_template.log', true);

                $emailTemplate->send($alert->getEmail(), $order->getStoreName(), $emailTemplateVariables);
                // Email template ends

            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::log($e->getMessage());
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
            }
        }    // Foreach loop ends
    }
    Mage::log('Mail Ends');
}
```

in `var/log/custom_email_template.log`
    2017-10-16T12:34:00+00:00 DEBUG (7): array (
      'username' => 'Saurabh Developer',
      'store_name' => 'Main Website
    You\'re So Vegan
    You\'re So Vegan',
      'store_url' => 'http://website_name.com/',
    )

Comment: Is their any error showing?

Comment: its sending some other email template, actually, i am modifying  a extension which already overided the core product_alert_stock module.

Comment: make sure you are using unique `custom_order_tpl` and use  `load` not `loadDefault`.

Comment: ok let me try with `  $emailTemplate->load('custom_order_qtyalert');`

Comment: with these variables new template is used ( as title is new) but no body content